# React: Unable to get table data to refresh after delete request is made to the api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

My aim is for the screen view to open, GET request the api and display the data returned in the table. Then when the Admin user clicks a delete button to delete a row a DELETE request is sent to the api and the table refreshes to remove the deleted row.

Screen.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Table, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { get_patient_list, delete_patient_by_id } from  '../actions/patientActions';

function PatientListScreen({ isAuthenticated, isAdmin }) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const patients = useSelector(state => state.patients)
    const { patientList } = patients

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(get_patient_list());
    }, [dispatch])

    const deleteHandler = (patient) => {
        if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete ${patient.first_name} ${patient.last_name} (${patient.patient_reference})?`)) {
            dispatch(delete_patient_by_id(patient.id));
            dispatch(get_patient_list());
        }
    };

    const patient_list_table = (
        <Fragment>
            <Table striped bordered hover responsive className='table-sm'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Px Ref</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>DOB</th>
                        <th>Contact Number</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {patientList ?
                        patientList.map(patient => (
                            <tr key={patient.id}>
                                <td>{patient.patient_reference}</td>
                                <td>{patient.first_name} {patient.last_name}</td>
                                <td>{patient.dob}</td>
                                <td>{patient.primary_phone_number} </td>
                                <td>{isAdmin ? (
                                            <LinkContainer to={`/admin/user/${patient.id}/edit`}>
                                                <Button variant='light' className='btn-sm'>
                                                    <i className='fas fa-edit'></i>
                                                </Button>
                                            </LinkContainer>
                                        ) : <p></p>}
                                </td>
                                <td>{isAdmin ? (
                                        <Button variant='danger' className='btn-sm' onClick={() => deleteHandler(patient)}>
                                            <i className='fas fa-trash'></i>
                                        </Button>
                                        ) : <p></p>}
                                </td>
                            </tr>))
                        : <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </Fragment>
    )
    
    if (isAuthenticated===false){
        return <Navigate to='/login' />;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Patients</h1>
            {isAuthenticated ? patient_list_table: null}
        </div>
        
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    isAdmin: state.auth.isAdmin
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(PatientListScreen);
```

Actions.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import {
    PATIENT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PATIENT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PATIENT_LIST_FAIL,
    PATIENT_DELETE_SUCCESS,
    PATIENT_DELETE_FAIL,
} from '../constants/userConstants';

export const get_patient_list = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: PATIENT_LIST_REQUEST
        });

        const { data } = await axios({
            method:'get', 
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/v1/patients/`, 
            xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
            xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFTOKEN',
            withCredentials: true
        });

        dispatch({
            type: PATIENT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PATIENT_LIST_FAIL
        });
    }
};

export const delete_patient_by_id = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {

    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method:'delete', 
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/v1/patients/delete/${id}/`, 
            xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
            xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFTOKEN',
            withCredentials: true
        })

        if (res.data.success) {
            dispatch({
                type: PATIENT_DELETE_SUCCESS
            });


        } else {
            dispatch({
                type: PATIENT_DELETE_FAIL
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: PATIENT_DELETE_FAIL
        });
    }
};
```

Reducers.js

```js
import {
    PATIENT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PATIENT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PATIENT_LIST_FAIL
} from "../constants/userConstants";

const initialState = {
    patientList: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case PATIENT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { 
                ...state
            }
        case PATIENT_LIST_SUCCESS:
        case PATIENT_LIST_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                patientList: payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    };
};
```

When the DELETE request runs, the api server records the below.

- [..] "OPTIONS /api/v1/patients/delete/18/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- [..] "GET /api/v1/patients/ HTTP/1.1" 200 682
- [..] "DELETE /api/v1/patients/delete/18/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17
  As the get request runs before the delete request meaning the table data is not up to date.

When adding "patientList" to the `useEffect` dependencies it repeatedly calls the GET request.

How should I adapt the code to achieve the required outcome.

Comment: Can you make a basic example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new? You can change the API calls for dummy ones like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that you want the `delete_patient_by_id` action to completely process and complete the backend DELETE request prior to refetching the patient list. Declare `deleteHandler` `async` and `await` the first asynchronous action to complete *then* dispatch the second action.

Example:

```js
const deleteHandler = async (patient) => {
  const {
    first_name: first,
    last_name: last,
    patient_reference: reference
  } = patient;

  const name = [first, last].filter(Boolean).join(" ");

  const prompt = `Are you sure you want to delete ${name} (${reference})?`;

  if (window.confirm(prompt)) {
    await dispatch(delete_patient_by_id(patient.id));
    dispatch(get_patient_list());
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Declaring 'deleteHandler' 'async' using 'await' has worked.